# Watir webdriver, using Firefox clicking on a link giving error - UnknownError: l is undefined, whereas in chrome its working fine

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have a web page (https://) in to this page whenever I'm trying to click on any link it is giving me weird error. This is giving me error when I'm using firefox browser to automate.
If I use chrome it is clicking on any link without giving any error.

HTML is like this:

```
<li id="tab2" class=""><a role="button" aria-pressed="false" id="tab2link" onfocus="onFocusLink(&quot;tab2link&quot;)" onblur="onBlurLink(&quot;tab2link&quot;)" href="/workplace/myportal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hLAyAwNTAwsvAKM‌​jbw9HQJdXYLCTU2CDYAykeaxRvgAI4GIN1OIGYASHeYM1C3ob-_ZaCfr4GBvxFENx55_HaHg1xrFu_nbx‌​TqZuJpaGhh5mpoYGTmYeLkE-Zp4O5iDJHH4zo_j_zcVP2C3NAIgywTRQDl3__u/?uri=nm:oid:6_B0000‌​P002GVC30IMJ4J6J400U3" style="outline: none; ">MyLink</a></li>
```

The error I'm getting is as follows :

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: l is undefined
        from [remote server] file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdrive r-profile20120921-5620-dorvjl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/comm and_processor.js:9497:in `unknown'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdrive r-profile20120921-5620-dorvjl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/comm and_processor.js:10131:in `unknown'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdrive r-profile20120921-5620-dorvjl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/comm and_processor.js:10136:in `unknown'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdrive r-profile20120921-5620-dorvjl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/comm and_processor.js:10074:in `unknown'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:65:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:358:in `clickElement'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/s elenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:108:in `click'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):007:0>
```

Can anyone help me out for this as this is completely out of my mind.

Watir code I'm using is a simple link clicking code by its text

```
browser.link(:text, "MyLink").click
```

Also if I pass any argument in click method like :shift or :control, it is working, it is clicking on the link but not without arguments, It is happening in firefox using watir-webdriver

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error.

Comment: Code is like this:                                                <li id="tab2" class=""><a role="button" aria-pressed="false" id="tab2link" onfocus="onFocusLink(&quot;tab2link&quot;)" onblur="onBlurLink(&quot;tab2link&quot;)" href="/workplace/myportal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hLAyAwNTAwsvAKMjbw9HQJdXYLCTU2CDYAykeaxRvgAI4GIN1OIGYASHeYM1C3ob-_ZaCfr4GBvxFENx55_HaHg1xrFu_nbxTqZuJpaGhh5mpoYGTmYeLkE-Zp4O5iDJHH4zo_j_zcVP2C3NAIgywTRQDl3__u/?uri=nm:oid:6_B0000P002GVC30IMJ4J6J400U3" style="outline: none; ">MyLink</a></li>

Comment: I have copied HTML code to the question. Please post Watir code that causes the error. Edit the question, do not post the code in comments.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: I am using firefox version 12.0

Comment: Is it possible for you to update Firefox?  Mine is running on 14.0.1 (i'm one version behind at the moment it seems) and I've not run into any problems.

Comment: I need to test it in same version of browser. can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your html shows an anchor element try this instead (I've had similar issues and do this to get around):

```
browser.a(:text, 'MyLink').click
```

Comment: I've tried this and this also not working, It is giving same error.

Comment: Try the following:                                                             browser.li(:id, 'tab2').a(:text, 'MyLink').click     (Maybe there are duplicate elements)

Comment: It's not working, I've already tried all this, even I've tried with full xpath to click on the link, but it is not working, (It is not working in firefox browser only, in other browsers it is working fine witout any error), also there is no duplicate element as it is working fine in other browser.

Comment: Would it be possible to send me a link to this so I could try?

Comment: No actually it is in intranet network so it will not be accessible from internet. Even I'm wondering why this is not working in this specific browser.